# Does Affinity Designer have this "distort" tool?

Tags: adobe-fireworks, affinity-designer

I think the tool's called "Distort" in Fireworks, but I'm not certain.

Basically, I could resize just one side of the image.

For example, from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Does Affinity Designer have something similar?

Comment: There's a [tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGZqXYd1czw)

Comment: It looks like "perspective".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** and it's available in Warp Group option: *Layer > Warp Group > Perspective*

(Layers window also has same option and it can be selected by clicking Warp Group icon).

[image]

Simply select the text layer and go to Warp Group options and select *Perspective* preset. The text layer becomes of part of a Warp Group. Then you'll see four control handles and you can drag any of them depending on you want the text to look. You can hold Shift key to control the effect while moving any point.

You can further apply same or more presets on the existing Warp Group in case you want to experiment more.

Once done, you also have option to convert the result into curves.

There's also a *Quad* preset in same option which gives a little different result.

Comment: In AffinityD the perspective warp group is not OK. Add diagonals to a rectangle and see, how they become curved. I found it when making experiments to write an answer for this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/164678/how-do-i-create-a-3d-perspective-floor-graphic-effect-in-illustrator-for-print Inkscape has perfectly working perspective envelope. AD's 1x1 mesh warp group (delete the extra nodes) can be manually adjusted for acceptable result if one has temporary diagonals and edge stroke  for guidance. I guess Affinity programmers have cut corners to get something published.

Comment: @EricWillis oh I didn't know it. I just tried the rectangle thing and yeah the diagonal becomes curved.

Comment: The bad perspective warp has been noticed from writings in Affinity forum. A Serif representative has picked it for investigations about half an year ago. See this https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/193226-warp-group-problems/ The next screenshot is taken from there https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8c3z.jpg

Comment: @EricWillis well unfortunately Affinity apps have been acquired by Canva. I don't have any positive hopes now.